# Google Play incorrectly detects, if application is installed or not

Tags: google-play-store

**td;dr**: *I see "Installed" button on many applications at Google Play which I never installed on any of my devices and which are not installed right now (happens only through website / PC). In addition, I have to login each time I click such "Installed" button even though I'm already logged-in.*

---

What's wrong with Google Play application's installation status:

- each time I browse some application, I can clearly see "Installed" even though this is not true (I don't have particular application installed on any of my devices and I never had it installed),
- each time I click this button, I must login, even though I am already logged in to Google Play (and even though I was logging-in again just a 15 minutes ago, while installing previous app),
- after I login I see the list of devices on which I can install given application (because it is not installed on any of it so far), but in the background there's still "Installed" button clearly visible.

How it is possible that 10+ years old Google service fails at it's very core -- i.e. providing me with the information what is or what isn't installed on any of my devices?

And why do I have to login again, even though I did it 15 minutes ago and even though I see my avatar and account information in the top-right corner of the webpage all the time.

**EDIT**: *The described problem occurs when browsing Google Play via browser (PC) **only**. It never occurs when using mobile version of Google Play service*.

Comment: Do you also see the Install button if you use Google Play from a PC?

Comment: Sorry, for missing a very important information. Please, read the edited question.